# An error occurred while running subprocess cordova just because of version problem

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4, ionic-native

Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=c:\Users\krishna kale\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8.x! Detected version: 17.0.1
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

getting this problem I didnt want to chnage my envirment variable is there any way to build this by changing dependencies in Application?
why this problem is occures?

Comment: apart of setting properly variables you should
1. close and open terminal to reflect changes
2. delete windows cache as this can ben sometimes cached and brings headache when trying to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ionic 1 - 3, you need to change the environment variables. I have tested Ionic 3 with other java version other than 1.8, and it didn't work.

The newer java version has a new path created under "System variables" > "Path" on the top.

You can retain 2 java versions and revert back to your current java version (17.0.1) once you have built your app.

You can follow these steps:

1. Download and Install Java SDK 1.8 from the official website.
2. Once installed, it should be saved in C:/Program Files/Java directory
3. Go to your Environment Variables > System variables
4. Click on "New.." to create a new variable.
5. Variable name = JAVA_HOME and Variable value = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321 or check on your directory.
6. Then double click on "Path" variable under System variables.
7. Click "New" and add %JAVA_HOME%\bin
8. Once created, select the newly created environment and move it to the very top (Make sure that it's above C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath)

Reverting back to original version

1. Go to System variables and double click on "Path"
2. Remove the newly created variable = %JAVA_HOME%\bin
3. You should get back your original java version.